# Package ‘TreeTagger’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)

Tags: r, treetagger

I try to install TreeTagger Package, but it is impossible for this version of R.
I get this error message :

```
> install.packages("TreeTagger", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/A579856/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘TreeTagger’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)
```

Any idea to help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true: No such file on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/

Are you looking for this tool? http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/

Apparantly the koRpus package can be used as a R wrapper to that. See heading 2.1 in it'S vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/koRpus/vignettes/koRpus_vignette.pdf

Comment: The link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/koRpus/vignettes/koRpus_vignette.pdf is broken. [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/koRpus/vignettes/koRpus_vignette.html) an up-dated one